# Testing that an array is ordered randomly

Tags: sorting, phpunit, shuffle

I am testing my code with [PHPunit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en). My code has several ordering-methods: by name, age, count and **random**. Below the implementation and test for sorting by count. These are pretty trivial.

```
class Cloud {
  //...
  public function sort($by_property) {
    usort($this->tags, array($this, "cb_sort_by_{$by_property}"));
    return $this;
  }

  private function cb_sort_by_name($a, $b) {
    $al = strtolower($a->get_name());
    $bl = strtolower($b->get_name());
    if ($al == $bl) {
      return 0;
    }
    return ($al > $bl) ? +1 : -1;
  }

  /**
   * Sort Callback. High to low
   */
  private function cb_sort_by_count($a, $b) {
    $ac = $a->get_count();
    $bc = $b->get_count();
    if ($ac == $bc) {
      return 0;
    }
    return ($ac < $bc) ? +1 : -1;
  }
}
```

Tested with:

```
  /**
   * Sort by count. Highest count first.
   */
  public function testSortByCount() {
    //Jane->count: 200, Blackbeard->count: 100
    //jane and blackbeard are mocked "Tags".
    $this->tags = array($this->jane, $this->blackbeard);

    $expected_order = array("jane", "blackbeard");
    $given_order = array();

    $this->object->sort("count");

    foreach($this->object->get_tags() as $tag) {
      $given_order[] = $tag->get_name();
    }

    $this->assertSame($given_order, $expected_order);
  }
```

But now, I want to add "random ordering"

```
  /**
   * Sort random.
   */
  public function testSortRandom() {
    //what to test? That "shuffle" got called? That the resulting array
    // has "any" ordering?
  }
```

The implementation could be anything from calling `shuffle($this->tags)` to a `usort` callback that returns 0,-1 or +1 randomly. Performance is an issue, but testability is more important.

How to test that the array got ordered randomly? AFAIK it is very hard to stub global methods like `shuffle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to implement this with a global-wrapper:

```
class GlobalWrapper {
  public function shuffle(&$array);
    shuffle($array);
  }
}
```

In the sort, I call `shuffle` through that wrapper:

```
public function sort($by_property) {
  if ($by_property == "random") {
    $this->global_wrapper()->shuffle($this->tags);
  }
  //...
}
```

Then, in the tests I can mock that `GlobalWrapper` and provide stubs for global functions that are of interest. In this case, all I am interested in, is that the method gets called, not what it outputs[1].

```
 public function testSortRandomUsesShuffle() {
   $global = $this->getMock("GlobalWrapper", array("shuffle"));
   $drupal->expects($this->once())
     ->method("shuffle");
   $this->object->set_global_wrapper($drupal);

   $this->object->sort("random");
 }
```

[1] In reality I have Unit Tests for this wrapper too, testing the parameters and the fact it does a call-by-ref. Also, this wrapper was already implemented (and called `DrupalWrapper`) to allow me to stub certain global functions provided by a third party (Drupal). This implementation allows me to pass in the wrapper using a `set_drupal()` and fetch it using `drupal()`. In above examples, I have called these `set_global_wrapper()` and  `global_wrapper()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) your method should look like this

```php
sortRandom() {
 return shuffle($this->tags);
}
```

Well, you don't need to test if keys are shuffled but if array is still returned.

```php
function testSortRandom(){
    $this->assertTrue(is_array($this->object->sortRandom()));
}
```

You should test your code, not php core code.

Comment: «You should test your code, not php core code.» True. This is why I prefer the way where you test that a certain method is called (`shuffle()`). I am not interested in whether or not that method works as expected; I should be able to trust PHP-core to have tested that.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not really possible in any meaningful sense. If you had a list with just a few items in, then it'd be entirely possible that sorting by random would indeed look like it's sorted by any given field (and as it happens the odds of it being in the same order as sorting by any other field are pretty high if you don't have too many elements)

Unit testing a sort operation seems a bit daft if you ask me though if the operation doesn't actually manipulate the data in any way. Feels like unit testing for the sake of it rather than because it's actually measuring that something works as intended.

Comment: Unit-testing a sort operation for three reasons: 100% coverage (itself not a goal, but still important), sorting is *not* trivial (try to sort `ÅÄÖABO` correct) and because BDD requires me to drive the code out using tests (write test, then implementation).